# pgRouting Win 7 installation problem

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I have run into a problem installing pgRouting. Following [**Anita Grasers guide**](http://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/), I have gotten as far as to execute the three .sql files.

The first sql file (routing_core) runs fine, but for the second and third (routing_core_wrappers and routing_topology), I get the following error message:

ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist
SQL state: 42704

I am using PostGreSQL 8.4 and have tested using PostGIS 1.4.2, 1.5, and 2.0. At first, I used a newer version of PostGreSQL, which ran into trouble at an earlier stage (thanks to all the answers provided to other posts, which aided me in getting me as far as this)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: installation issue with pgsql, most likely. did you copy dlls at right location?

Comment: I've written a new guide http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/ try that.